# wrapbootstrap jquery not working with angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [wrapbootstrap theme - ace](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR).

I have html page using **angularjs using yeoman, karma and grunt**. There I am using the ace theme. The angularjs is working fine for me. But the wrapbootstrap theme is not working properly. Some Jquery works, but some not. Here is my **index.html** page structure.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS imports -->
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div class="navbar">
 <!--  Page top header and left side menus -->
 <div ng=view="">
 </div>
</div>
<!-- basic scripts -->

    <!--[if !IE]> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='styles/assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>

    <!-- <![endif]-->

    <!-- [if IE]> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='styles/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>
    <!-- <![endif] -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if("ontouchend" in document) document.write("<script src='styles/assets/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js'>"+"<"+"/script>");
    </script>
    <script src="styles/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="styles/assets/js/typeahead-bs2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- page specific plugin scripts -->

    <!-- ace scripts -->

    <script src="styles/assets/js/ace-elements.min.js"></script>
    <script src="styles/assets/js/ace.min.js"></script>

    <!-- inline scripts related to this page -->

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <!-- build:js scripts/plugins.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-affix.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/modules.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/invoiceUpload.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

I get like the following image. The left side menu is able to minimize. But the top right menus notification and profile drop-downs are not working. Those drop-downs are using the `<a href="#">Welcome</a>`

I thought it is because the **href=#** interrupting by the **angularjs routing** so I removed the **#** from that. And it is still not working.
[image]

I removed 3 first 3 scripts imported inside  tag. So I get like following image. The top menus are working. But left menu is not able to minimize and showing JQuery error in console that **Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined**.

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have ng=view="" in your code. It should be ng-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the html you posted looks like you try to use conditional comments with non IE browsers. Apart from this, since you close the comment, shouldn't influence jQuery from being loaded by the browser.

Another possible reason is that you are using the wrong path to load jquery: I see `styles/assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js` and `bower_components/jquery/jquery.js` maybe you should check which one is the correct one and move to the top.

Comment: I tried adding the `bower_components/jquery/jquery.js` first and removed the `styles/assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js`. But it is still not working.

Comment: I tried removing all the JS inside `bower_components/bootstrap-sass/js`. And it is working. But shows some error in console. But the problem is in future may be I need to use these scripts.

Comment: Without removing the bootstrap-sass js components, just put `<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>` at the top of the page, to see if it works

Comment: I tried putting it as the first script import. The result is still the same

Comment: If your issue is resolved please tell what was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not currently support jQuery 2.x or above
https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq